# How can I activate the terminal?

Tags: command-line, shortcuts

How can I activate the terminal?
Is the only way to click on the icon in the far left upper corner the only way?
Thanks for a shortcut,
John

Comment: Ctrl+Alt+T should be another shortcut to open terminal.

Comment: You haven't told us much (your version of Ubuntu, your desktop etc), but in most cases hitting CTRL + ALT + T will open a terminal in Ubuntu

Comment: Or you can define it yourself by going into keyboard settings.

Comment: Or from Nautilus right-click menu (Open in Terminal).